# What tag to use for Captain America 2?

Tags: discussion, tags

The full title of the upcoming second *Captain America* film is *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*.  The issue here is that the full title is too long for the 25 character limit tags have, and *The Winter Soldier* is also the name of a comic book arc.  So we need a tag that differentiates from the comic arc, while being less than 25 characters.

What tag should we use?

Comment: At the moment, I made 'ca2-the-winter-soldier' for this.

Comment: I know some people don't like them, but you could also use the [tag:movie] media tag in addition to a winter soldier tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about [captain-america-tws](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-tws)?

There's some precedent for abbreviating suffixes in titles, e.g. [star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng), [star-trek-ds9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-ds9), [my-little-pony-fim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-little-pony-fim).

Comment: Done. (padding characters)