# What tags should we rename now that we have 35 characters in tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

[We now can use up to 35 characters in tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490)! Hooray! This means that now we can rename some awkward tags that weren't able to be created well because of the 25 character limit. However, as [@AnkitSharma points out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39316690#39316690), creating a meta post for each tag that should be renamed would be silly. Instead, here's a master list. Please edit the community wiki answer below with the list of tags that should be renamed now that we can have more characters. Please link to the appropriate meta question if one already exists.

Note: **this doesn't have to mess up the front page**. Tag renames can be done almost silently by mods (although one bump may be required per rename).

Comment: No, there's *no* bump required per rename if the moderators do it.

Comment: @TARS - interesting. I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 12):

These tags need to be renamed:

- (**done**) [jonathan-strange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jonathan-strange) → [jonathan-strange-and-mr-norrell](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jonathan-strange-and-mr-norrell)
- (**done**) [captain-america-tws](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-tws) → [captain-america-the-winter-soldier](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-the-winter-soldier) ([old meta post about it](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/what-tag-to-use-for-captain-america-2))
- (**done**) [captain-america-tfa](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-tfa) → [captain-america-the-first-avenger](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-the-first-avenger)
- (**done**) [charlie-and-the-chocolate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charlie-and-the-chocolate) → [charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory)
- (**done**) [tmnt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tmnt) → [teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles) ([relevant meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11233/33591))
- (**done**) [dada](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dada) → [defence-against-the-dark-arts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defence-against-the-dark-arts)
- (**done**) [batman-v-superman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman-v-superman) → [batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice)
- (**done**) [extraordinary-gentlemen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extraordinary-gentlemen) → [league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen) ([relevant meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10193/why-is-there-a-25-character-tag-limit))
- [federation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/federation) → [the-united-federation-of-planets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-united-federation-of-planets)([relevant meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/should-we-rename-the-federation-tag-to-star-trek-federation))
- [guardians-of-the-galaxy-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-2) → [guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2)  ([relevant meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/should-we-fix-the-guardians-of-the-galaxy-tags))
- [guardians-of-the-galaxy-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-1) → [guardians-of-the-galaxy-2014](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-2014) ([relevant meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/should-we-fix-the-guardians-of-the-galaxy-tags))
- **(done)** [terminator3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator3) → [terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines)
- [terminator2-judgement-day](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator2-judgement-day) → [terminator-2-judgement-day](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator-2-judgement-day)
- [magnus-chase](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnus-chase) → [magnus-chase-and-the-gods-of-asgard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnus-chase-and-the-gods-of-asgard)
- [sw-the-old-republic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-the-old-republic) → [star-wars-the-old-republic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-the-old-republic)
- [slow-regardsilent-things](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slow-regardsilent-things) → [the-slow-regard-of-silent-things](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-slow-regard-of-silent-things)
- [sarah-connor-chronicles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sarah-connor-chronicles) → [terminator-sarah-connor-chronicles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator-sarah-connor-chronicles)
- *add in the format `[tag:tag name] → [tag:longer-tag-name] [link to meta if applicable](https://example meta.stackexchange.com/q/12345)`*

Comment: @Mithrandir why have you removed ds9? Deep Space Nine is it's full title.

Comment: @edlo see the Restaurant

Comment: @JonSnow I was wrong gotg1 was never called vol. 1 , Monsieur daaahwhooosh made a valid edit!

Comment: Although my new quibble is as Creation said below, do we need to add 'the' everywhere?

Comment: @Edlothiad [retroactively referred to as Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(film))

Comment: @Edlothiad I think it's better to go with official title and if official title have it then it should be kept ( except when we have to trim it due to 35 limit )

Comment: @jonsnow Ah yes that was part of daaaaaahwhooooosh and my discussion. Time to change it in the post

Answer (score 4):

Here's a dead-simple query that might help find tags that can be improved, instead of manually searching through the Tags page.

https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/708480/tags-that-might-benefit-from-increased-tag-length

Fork it if you'd like. Currently, I have it set to find tags of length 16-25, meaning they may have the potential to benefit from the additional limit.

I do notice there's a large number of tags where the official titles contain "the" but the tag does not. I suggest having a discussion on whether we *want* all those "the"s added before submitting them for the rename. (*The* Dark Knight Rises may not be necessary, but what about Star Trek: *The* Motion Picture? Something to chew on)

Comment: Also, things like [Narnia] vs. [the-chronicles-of-narnia] (re about *the*).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an existing meta post about whether or not tags should contain things like "a" and "the" (the conclusion being that we're inconsistent as hell), but obviously that's very hard to search for, and I haven't managed to unearth a link.

Comment: @Randal'Thor And still under the context of 25-character limits, where those articles were more likely to waste space than anything.