# Should [star-trek-eu] be renamed [star-trek-expanded-universe]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag for the [*Star Trek* expanded universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_expanded_universe) is currently [star-trek-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-eu). Since we can use longer tag names for quite a while now, should we rename that to [star-trek-expanded-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-expanded-universe) and use the old tag as a synonym?

If so, would a mod please be so kind?

This has been discussed as part of [a general proposal for [star-trek-*] tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11589/19561), but no decision has been made as far as I can see. That's why I've narrowed my request down to just one tag.

---

<sub>Note that the proper name is [*Star Trek* **expanded** universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_expanded_universe) instead of *extended* universe.</sub>

Comment: Makes sense to me. I can't remember exactly how synonyms work but is this not something we can do ourselves... i.e. create `[star-trek-expanded-universe]` and make eu a synonym of it. Would it not then auto switch them around?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot in these cases, it's best if a mod does this since they can change it in one fell swoop.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Even if you get the 5 approvals for the synonym proposal (and *noone* really knows they can/should approve tag synonyms), you would still need a moderator to switch all the old questions over to the new tag (unless you want one of these dreaded frontpage messup sessions), since that doesn't happen automatically upon synonym approval.

Comment: @TARS Ah that's what I was wondering about, if it auto swapped them or not.

Comment: This is a direct dupe that’s been answered and implemented elsewhere

Comment: @TARS given there's no easy way of seeing the proposals, it's hard to know, or to find when you can/should approve them.

Comment: "no decision has been made" -> the top voted answer (+20/-5) literally states "How about using the full names as synonyms for the acronyms?"

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot which hasn't been implemented as far as I can see.

Comment: @SQB Just because it hasn't been implemented doesn't mean that's not the way the community wants to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Make it so.

Rename the current tag to [star-trek-expanded-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-expanded-universe) and make [star-trek-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-eu) a synonym.